# Larged Paged Pool in C# program .... what is this?

Tags: c#

I have a serverside c# program running 24/7. After a few days the Processes 'Paged Pool' (as displayed in Windows Task Manager) is building up to 12 MB when it reaches 13-14 Mb the machine blue screens. The main 'Mem usage' is 180 mb,

I am running 32-bit Windows Server 2003 SP2.

The question is; What is the 'Paged Pool'? What in my C# program could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: `Windows Server 2002 SP2`? Also how do you expect to get an answer when you didn't even say what your program is doing? There could be infinity of reasons why your program is allocating memory.

Comment: BSOD is caused by kernel or driver failure, so it may very well be totally unrelated to the behavior of your .NET application.

Comment: Monitor the number of threads and handles (using Task Manager or PerfMon); if either value rises regularly you have a resource leak. Most likely an object is not disposing of a native handle (e.g. database connection).

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Paged Pool is a section of memory set aside by the Windows kernel for satisfying demands from the kernel and device drivers for memory which can be paged to disk, as opposed to memory which should never be paged to disk. (For an in-depth look, read: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx)

I don't see how your process could be allocating Paged Pool, since it is managed by the kernel, however, given that you are getting a blue screen, there could be some connection. Are you using the Registry or Memory Mapped files at all? Those are big consumers of Paged Pool resources. Perhaps you are reading a lot of registry entries over the life of the process and never releasing them. However, as you can see from the above article, exhausing the paged pool won't blue screen, but perhaps you have a hardware device which is crashing on exhaustion.

Ultimately, you'd need to get more details about the problem, since a number of things could be going on here. Recording the Stop Error code, describing what the program does, etc., will all help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you programme is acquiring memory and not releasing it.

Do you have an infinite loop running where objects that implement `IDisposable` are being created?

Check that they are being disposed of somewhere in the loop, either by calling `Dispose` on them directly, or wrapping them in a `using` block.